# Outlook 2010 repeatedly tries to download html file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, download, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've recently started experiencing this odd behavior - Outlook opens a dialog asking to download html file which seems to be a cache of recent browsing:

[image]

Have anyone encountered such thing?
I've inspected the Windows task scheduler, but haven't found anything suspicious.
I suspect it's a virus, have no other explanation.

Comment: Are you facing this problem with emails or attachments?

Comment: Which is your default browser? Try to download the latest version of the default browser and install it, otherwise set the Internet Explorer to your default browser.

Comment: Which OS you are using? Take a look on this [article](http://www.sandiego.edu/its/kb/85516) and report back if it works?

Comment: I'm using Win7, will try to reset the default browser nonetheless

Comment: That didn't work (I changed default browser back to Chrome again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well people have some different solutions for this problem.

Go to **`"view/people pane"`** and set to **off**.

Or you can try

Go to **Internet Properties→Programs→Internet Program (set programs)** and 
reset `Program Access and Computer Defaults` to the `Microsoft Windows option`.

All information is from [Outlook keeps trying to download some html file](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/outlook-keeps-trying-download-some-html-file-t4028987.html). Also same solution is suggested on [Google Product forum](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/9Q7SS86gOGM/9Rwna4qIxPoJ)

Comment: Yes, I've found this solution too. Disabled the `people pane` and reset to `Microsoft Windows` - after that, however, I've went back to  my custom config, since I don't want the IE to be default browser. Giving it a day to see if the problem was resolved.

Comment: Seems to be working (not sure though which of the changes did the trick).

Answer (score 1):

Goto File->Options->Add-Ins, at the right bottom of the screen, you will see Manage -> COM Add-ins, click on Go, from the list of options uncheck this option: 'Microsoft Outlook Social Connector', click on OK. Restart Outlook and see if it fixes the issue.